# deduct an integer value from SQL database html?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to learn html, php and all of that. So what im trying to do right now is, I have created a SQL database in phpmyadmin, it's just a name and an integer value like:

- Nickname 20
- Nickname 30
- bank 10 and etc.

So what I want to do now is:

```
var textil= 20;
function displayImage(){
if (textil >= 2) {

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
    textil=textil-2;    
    } else {
     alert("Insufficient funds.");
    }
}
```

This is what I did before, and it works now, but now comes the real problem for me because I have no idea how to do this, how do I deduct that "textil" value from the SQL database instead from a var.

like when i click, ofc onclick=displayimage(); it goes -2 on the textil value, but from SQL not this in html. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way to access your SQL database directly from the browser.

You will probably need a Server which will access the SQL database.

After you have retrieved the data, there are two methods to feed this data to your webpage:

1) AJAX - the technology which drives the mordern web. Look it up and study it thoroughly

2) Use a programming language capable of generating HTML output. Access your data from SQL, and generate the relevant javascript based on it.

You mentioned you are learning php. Go a few chapters deep into it and you will get your answer.